# unbind and bind click event on specific screen width

Tags: jquery

I am trying to bind and unbind a click even on a specific screen width. When the page starts at a screen width less than 768px the click event works like it should. When I resize it to a larger screen the click event is unbinded just like it should BUT when I resize the screen back to less than 768px my click event does NOT work like I want it too. Any advice?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {     
      $(".custom-filter").click(function(){
          $(".fa").toggle();
          $("#test").slideToggle("slow");
      });  

      // I want to bind and unbind this click event 
      $("div.filter-group-shop-by-collecti h4").bind("click", (function () {
          $("ul.nav-shop-by-collecti").slideToggle("slow");
      }));      

      $(window).on('resize', function(){
            var win = $(this);
            if (win.width() >= 768) { 
                $("div.filter-group-shop-by-collecti h4").unbind("click");
            } else {
                $("div.filter-group-shop-by-collecti h4").bind("click");
            }      
      });   
});
```

Comment: need more specification please attached code here

Comment: look at your else, and the bind in there. There's no function being bound.

Comment: When i use the bind function in the else and when I click the button, the toggle event triggers multiple times because of the resize function.

Comment: I am using media queries as well

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
    $(document).ready(function() {     
  $(".custom-filter").click(function(){
      $(".fa").toggle();
      $("#test").slideToggle("slow");
  });  

  function toggleSlideShow(){
    $("ul.nav-shop-by-collecti").slideToggle("slow");
  }


  $(window).load(function() {
      if($(window).width() >= 768) {
          $("div.filter-group-shop-by-collecti h4").unbind();
      }
  });  

  // I want to bind and unbind this click event 
  $("div.filter-group-shop-by-collecti h4").bind("click", toggleSlideShow);      

  $(window).on('resize', function(){
        var win = $(this);
        if (win.width() >= 768) { 
            $("div.filter-group-shop-by-collecti h4").unbind();
        } else {
            $("div.filter-group-shop-by-collecti h4").unbind();
            $("div.filter-group-shop-by-collecti h4").bind("click", toggleSlideShow);
        }      
  });    
});
```